Flutter - How to change the state of a bool on my widget
this is my info_card
class InfoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String value;
  final Color topColor;
  final bool isActive;
  final Function() onTap;

  const InfoCard({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.value,
    required this.topColor,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Container(
          height: 120,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    offset: const Offset(0, 6),
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.1),
                    blurRadius: 12),
              ],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: topColor,
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: TextSpan(children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: "$title\n",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: isActive
                                ? colorScheme.primary
                                : colorScheme.onBackground)),
                    TextSpan(
                        text: value,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40,
                            color: isActive
                                ? colorScheme.primary
                                : colorScheme.onBackground)),
                  ])),
              Expanded(child: Container())
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

and this is the card on my dashboard
InfoCard(
                title: "Scylla Serrata",
                value: "56",
                topColor: Colors.brown,
                isActive: false,
                onTap: () {}),

I want to change the isActive to true so that the card text color will be updated. Hence, highlighting it for better user experience. However, i don't know how to change the isActive which is currently 'false' to true so that the color will change when clicked. Any help please.

lets say you are going to use your InfoCard() widget in View,
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class View extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ViewState createState() => _ViewState();
}

class _ViewState extends State<View> {
  // define a boolean where you are going to use your InfoCard() widget and set its value to false 
  bool isActive = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("View"),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          InfoCard(
            title: "View",
            value: "56",
            topColor: Colors.brown,
            isActive: isActive,
            onTap: () {
              // in the onTap() method call setState and change the value fo the boolean
              setState(() {
                isActive = !isActive; // Toggle the isActive state
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

let me know if it was helpful.

It didn't work at first but I realized i didn't put the variable on the top of the Widget build. Clearly my bad. THANK YOU BRO! God bless you!
